# How to add libraries to angularjs app by using webpack?

Tags: angularjs, webpack, devextreme

I'm using angularJs and i'm trying to use webpack but i can't understand how to add libraries like angular-material  / devextreme.

Here is an example of my app.js file - as you can see - the import of devextreme is probably wrong ...

```
import angular from 'angular';
import { DxButtonModule } from 'devextreme-angular'; // not sure about it
 
var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', [DxButtonModule]); // really not sure about it...
mainApp.controller('appController',  ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.title ='Hello Angular';
}]
)
```

b.t.w - can i import all devextreme modules in one time instead of each of them manually?